# How do I get rid of `.js` extensions on my imports when using Typescript with ESModules?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I'm working on a node.js project written with TypeScript. I needed a ESM-only dependency for my project so I decided to transform my tsc config to target esmodules. The problem I came across was that when I try import files like in CJS (eg `./foo/bar` to import `./foo/bar/index.ts`) the transformed bundle has incorrect imports (esm requires full paths to imported files with extensions). And when I try to rewrite the imports using `.ts` extensions this doesn't work either because tsc doesn't change `.ts` imports to `.js`. It's a known issue and there were many discussions about it, I'm not here to criticise TS team, I just don't want to import files that don't exist in my code (eg writing `./foo/bar/index.js` to import `./foo/bar/index.ts`).

Can someone direct me to a good `tsc` alternative that will allow me to use my regular import statements (omitting `index` and file extensions) but that will transform my code with adding `.js` extensions to the bundle files?

edit: I should add that I'm writing a CLI and not a web app, so Vite and Webpack are kinda out of the question on that one (?) or maybe not, I'm not sure is it even possible to transform a project without index.html with Vite, for example